# python script won't run at startup ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, mqtt, paho

I try to run my python scrip at startup but it doesn't work.

Here is my python script(doesn't work):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
from datetime import datetime

t = str(datetime.now())
print t
with open("/home/james/mqtt/log.txt", "a+") as f:
    f.write("it works " + t + "\n")
```

Here is my python script(works):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import datetime

t = str(datetime.now())
print t
with open("/home/james/mqtt/log.txt", "a+") as f:
    f.write("it works " + t + "\n")
```

Here is my rc.local files(also try crontab and setting up service in /ect/init.d):

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# /bin/mqtt_test.py &
# mosquitto_sub -t "mqtt"

/home/james/mqtt/script.sh
# /etc/mqtt/mqtt_test.py

exit 0
```

It look like by importing paho.mqtt.publish can make my script stop working, I am new to Linux, I have no idea why. Can someone help me out? Thanks for your help.

Ubuntu 16.04

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: You can get the error with the `paho.mqtt.publish` using a `try` block around that import. I think the script while running at boot time, couldn't find the module in default path and you may have to specify it in your `rc.local` file

Comment: @jprockbelly I don't see error message, or I don't know how to get the error message. I should also add, my script works fine if I run it normally like this ./script.py

Comment: @James Wu, can you wrap that import in try block like -
`try:
    import paho.mqtt.publish
 except Exception as ex:
    print ex.message`. Maybe write the error message in a file

Comment: @kuro I will try both of your suggestion and report back, cheers!

Comment: @kuro, I tried wrap that import in a try block, here is the error message: No module named paho.mqtt.publish. I think your first comment is correct, I need to somehow provide the default path for my script

Comment: Hi @kuro, thanks for your help, my script couldn't find the module. Guessing the `$PATHONPATH` is not set yet. Adding this to the `rc.local` file fix my problem: `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/my/packet`. In my case, it's: 
`export 
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/james/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem myself. For me the problem was path. I could get it working by using a shell script to launch a python script and launch the shell script from crontab.

Here is my `launcher.sh`. You may not use sudo if you do not want. `home/pi/record_data` is the path where my file resides.

```
cd /
cd home/pi/record_data
sudo python record_video.py
```

In this case `record_video.py` is the python file I want to run at startup. In the crontab edit, I added this line below.

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/record_data/launcher.sh &
```

Do try this out if it work for you :) Good luck.
I have not got the logging the error into files working yet though.

Answer (score -1):

it looks to me like you need to set/change the write permissions of the file before your python scrypt do this:

```
f.write("it works " + t + "\n")
```

for you is working because (maybe you are the owner of the file).

typical linux file permission is described as:

[image]

do use the **chmod** with the property flags, so **linux** has the rights to write the file too, please refer to the [**ubuntu** help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) :)